# Add value to arrayList in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add int values to array list

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylistPage1;

for(int j=1;j<=totalPage;j++){  
     int x=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=rangeMode;i++){
          if(binaryTable[i][j]==1){
             cardInPage[j][x]=i;
             System.out.println("card number: "+i);
             arraylistPage1.add(i);
             System.out.println(arraylistPage1);
             x++;                   
          }
     }
     System.out.println("page-"+j+" total card:"+x);
     totalCardInPage[j]=x;
}
```

But when I run it, the program just stops.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you step through it with a debugger to find out what's actually happening while it's "stopped".

Comment: What if ``totalPage == 0``?

Comment: @Vakh the totalpage will never be 0 in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to this,

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylistPage1;

for(int j=1;j<=totalPage;j++){  
 int x=0;
 arraylistPage1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
 for(int i=1;i<=rangeMode;i++){
      if(binaryTable[i][j]==1){
         cardInPage[j][x]=i;
         System.out.println("card number: "+i);
         arraylistPage1.add(i);
         System.out.println(arraylistPage1);
         x++;                   
      }
 }
 System.out.println("page-"+j+" total card:"+x);
 totalCardInPage[j]=x;
}
```